# Best way to implement a method specific to a class but does not directrly uses the attributes

Tags: python, class, object

I have a class which stores data and allows me to update it given some measurements. However, the update step does not take directly the attribute as is, but a modified version. Same goes with the output of my update: I still have to process it before saving it into the object attribute.

```
class Dummy:
    def _prepare_data(self):
        X = self.X
        # Do stuff to X
        return X_prepared
   
    @staticmethod
    def _update(X_prep, measures):
        # Do stuff to X_prep with measures
        return X_updated

    def _store_result(self, X_up):
        # Do stuff to X_up
        self.X = X_up_good_format

    def do_update(self, measures):
        # Method called from the outside, user doesn't care about data prep
        X = self._prepare_data()
        X = self._update(X, measures)
        self._store_results(X)
```

In this case, my private method `_update` is blind to the class as I don't need nor attributes or methods of my class, but it doesn't make sense for me to put it as a simple function outside because it doesn't "live on its own", it only exists to be used in this class. I've therefore put the method as a static method (as in the example) but I've read that doing so was a sign of bad design because it goes against OOP paradigm. Is there a better way to do this?

PS: I'd rather not merge the three private methods because I want to be able to call the method `_update` independently for testing purposes.

Comment: `staticmethod` is one word, no underscore.

Comment: Having a static method to perform a specific well-thought-out task is not a problem.

Comment: You know, if you replaced all your *do stuff with* and used a simple transformation to illustrate your point, you'd have running code that is easier to reason about.  ex:  `def _update(X_prep, measures): return X_prep + measures + "._updated"`.  It doesn't have to be meaningful but it runs and is less confusing to reason about.  It seems like there is a good question buried in there somewhere but too hard to reason about.

Comment: I like the property-based suggestion but if you care re. testing from the outside, consider using @classmethod for the formatting methods.  `_update(cls, x, y)` - makes them callable wo instance `Dummy._update(xxx, yyy)`  however your normal methods/properties can still call them with `self._update(xx,yy)`, the self gets converted to the class reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would address your concern is to merge `_update` with `do_update` into one, and make `_prepare_data` and `_store_result` into a single [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Dummy:
    @property
    def X(self):
        X = self._X
        # Do stuff to X
        return X_prepared

    @X.setter
    def X(self, value):
        # Do stuff to value
        self._X = value_good_format

    def do_update(self, measures):
        # Method called from the outside, user doesn't care about data prep
        # Do stuff to self.X with measures
        self.X = X_updated
```

Now child classes can override just the `do_update` method, while still relying on the conversions provided by the property `X`.